# Cypress says disabled attribute always has value "disabled"

Tags: cypress

I have an HTML element with a `disabled` attribute that is either `true` or `false, like:

```
<div class="row" disabled="false">
```

or

```
<div class="row" disabled="true">
```

I thought this would be straightforward to verify in Cypress by doing something like:

```
cy.get("div.row").should("have.attr", "disabled", "false")
```

However, when I tried that the test fails because Cypress reports that the `disabled` attribute of the element does not have the value "false" but instead has the value "disabled".

If I open the browser inspection tool I can verify that the attribute is shown as I've written above. Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

See [HTML attribute: disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled)

> The Boolean `disabled` attribute, **when present**, makes the element not mutable, focusable, or even submitted with the form.

This means it is either present or not, it doesn't take a value.

Any value you do give it, either "true", "false", or "something else" cause the element to be disabled - simply because the attribute is there.

The assertion `.should('have.attr', 'disabled', 'false')` is not behaving as expected, the correct assertion for the disabled attribute is `.should('be.disabled')`